# How do I ensure an API highlights text while the user simultaneously is editing that text?

Tags: javascript, api, race-condition

On our web app, we have a textarea where we process user input and highlight certain text (similar to MS Word, Grammarly, etc.). We make an API call to the back-end, and it processes the text and decides which parts of the text to highlight (the API returns the string's indices and the front-end JavaScript does the highlighting based on those indices). However, there will be race conditions where the user edits the text before the API returns a response. If that happens, the API could potentially highlight the wrong words, try to highlight words that the user just deleted, or miss highlighting text it should have.

The only way I can think of to solve this is to make frequent API calls, so that if the user makes a change in the middle of an API call, we make another call to fix any wrong highlighting. Is there a better way?

Comment: Debounce your backend calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea sounds totally reasonable to me. You could add a timestamp of when the text was last changed to the request which is then also returned.

If changes have been made in the meantime, the response is not longer valid and a new request is probably already on its way.

As @VLAZ mentioned, you could also debounce the number of requests, so they don’t happen after each letter that is inserted.